# Analysis of a matrix and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a nonnegative matrix $B$ with dominant eigenvalue $\mu$. Let $s>\lambda$.

1. Is it true that $s>b_{ij}, \forall i,j$?
2. What significance does the matrix $(sI-B)^{-1}$ have, if any special significance?

---

Other notes: Suppose $s=\mu$ then the matrix $(sI-B)^{-1}$ does not exist and $sI-B$ is singular. Is this correct?

Comment: Your "other notes" are indeed correct

Comment: A type of matrix along the lines of what you may be looking for is the [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessarily the case that $s > b_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.  For example, consider
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&9\\1&1}
$$
which has dominant eigenvalue $4$.